# function with variable arguments in kernel mode

Tags: c, windows, kernel, printf

I am trying to implement function with variable params in kernel mode.

call to function:

**a,b,c** are integer variables

```
WriteLogFile("test of trace logs=%d =%d =%d \n",a,b,c);

Function:

NTSTATUS WriteLogFile(const char* str,...)

{

va_list vl;

va_start(vl,str);

RtlStringCbPrintfA(buffer, sizeof(buffer), str,vl);

then i am using zwwriteffile to write usermode text file.

va_end(vl);

}
```

**output:**

> test of trace logs=1953719889=-1681971698 =1953719668

I am getting some garbage values. why?

Comment: I would first verify you're getting the arguments you think you are, with a call to [`DbgPrintEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff543634.aspx). View the debug messages with [DebugView](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896647.aspx).

Comment: we need to use va_arg to retrieve variables passed second param will tell type of argument passed(int, char etc).
Thank you Jonathon Reinhart I am not getting values in DbgView.